# i need help to iterate through an array that is in a functions parameter

Tags: javascript

- multiply param b by each index in the array argument.
- this only outputs 25. a[0] "5" is only being multiplied by argument b "5"
- intended output 25, 15, 30
- THANK YOU -Antonio

  ```
  function max(a,b) {
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  return  a[i]*b;
  }
  }
  alert(max([5,3,6],5));
  ```

Comment: JavaScript has built in support for this: `.map`. Example: `var result = [5, 3, 6].map(function(v) { return v * 5; });`

Answer (score 0):

return terminates the execution of function and returns the value. As you are using return in for loop, after going to loop once, it will return the value.

```
function max(a,b) {
var res = [];
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       res[i] = a[i]*b;
   }
return res;
}
alert(max([5,3,6],5));
```

Comment: much appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks. Please up vote and mark it as answer if this solves your problem.